# implementing activity that is a possible successor to all other activities in an acitivity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

i am currently doing an dynamic model for my ojt project. but i am stuck on a particular problem, my idea of a solution just seems overly complex.

to explain it in a different context, lets say i have 2 classes: customer and salesperson. the customer is buying something from the customer. but before everything is settled, they have to undergo a series of activities. after each activity, both the customer AND the salesperson have to chance to back out of the transaction. put in a diagram it looks like this:

[image]

is this correct? how about when i have like 50 possible activities? then that diagram will become very unreadable. what is a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at InterruptibleActivityRegion in the UML spec (section 12.3.33 of UML 2.4.1 superstructure ), it gives a similar example of cancelling an order at any point before the transaction is agreed. Within the interruptible region, which is notated as a dashed rounded rectangle with a Z shaped arrow coming out of it, all the activities may be interrupted by the event associated with the arrow - in your case backing out - and end up in the interruption handling activities.

Answer (score 1):

You should use interruptible activity region. For a quick reference, see this sample diagram:

[image: Interruptible Activity Region]